# Listening to Firebase extension events outside of the default channel/region and in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-extensions

I am trying to listen to the `invoice.paid` event triggered by the Stripe Payments extension, and I'm following [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/custom-events), trying to adapt examples to the fact all my code is in TypeScript. Another thing is that I deployed the extension to a region that's different from the default `us-central1` so that my extensions are hosted in the EU, just like my cloud functions.

So here is what my `firestore-stripe-payments.env` looks like:

```
ALLOWED_EVENT_TYPES=com.stripe.v1.invoice.paid,com.stripe.v1.invoice.payment_succeeded,com.stripe.v1.invoice.payment_failed,com.stripe.v1.invoice.upcoming
CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION_MIN_INSTANCES=0
CUSTOMERS_COLLECTION=users
DELETE_STRIPE_CUSTOMERS=Do not delete
EVENTARC_CHANNEL=projects/${param:PROJECT_ID}/locations/europe-west4/channels/firebase
LOCATION=europe-west1
PRODUCTS_COLLECTION=products
STRIPE_API_KEY=projects/${param:PROJECT_NUMBER}/secrets/firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_API_KEY/versions/latest
STRIPE_CONFIG_COLLECTION=configuration
STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET=projects/${param:PROJECT_NUMBER}/secrets/firestore-stripe-payments-STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET/versions/latest
SYNC_USERS_ON_CREATE=Sync
```

Then in my `index.ts`, I have the following to try and subscribe the `invoice.paid` event:

```js
import {onCustomEventPublished} from "firebase-functions/v2/eventarc";

export const onInvoicePaid = onCustomEventPublished(
    {
      eventType: "com.stripe.v1.invoice.paid",
      channel: "projects/[MY_PROJECT_ID]/locations/europe-west4/channels/firebase",
      region: "europe-west4",
    },
    (event) => {
      functions.logger.debug(`[onInvoicePaid] Received event: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
      return null;
    });
```

But even though it is successfully deployed, this function is never called, as evidenced by the fact that the Stripe Payment extension itself logs that it successfully processed an `invoice.paid` event, but the log in `onInvoicePaid` does not show up in the logs.

I updated all the NPM dependencies of my Cloud Functions so I'm using firebase-admin version 11.7.0 and firebase-functions 4.3.1.

I feel like I'm making a mistake somewhere and my event ends up in a black hole. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score -2):

> But even though it is successfully deployed, this function is never called

Then double-check the event routine configuration, either [through console](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/run/route-trigger-cloud-firestore#console), or [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/run/route-trigger-cloud-firestore#gcloud).

For instance, make sure you did enable the Cloud Logging, Eventarc, and Eventarc Publishing APIs.

```bash
gcloud services enable logging.googleapis.com \
  eventarc.googleapis.com \
  eventarcpublishing.googleapis.com
```

And make sure the API related to the direct events is enabled.
For example, for Cloud Functions events, enable `cloudfunctions.googleapis.com`.

Double-check your service account has the Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles or permissions for authenticated or unauthenticated invocations.

---

Try also to align the LOCATION as and the EVENTARC_CHANNEL location as in your `firestore-stripe-payments.env` file. Change LOCATION to `europe-west4`.